How to hide test history from VS Code test results

When I run tests using Command+;, C, it runs tests and show result.  But for some reason its now started showing this test history highlighted in red box.
I need a way to either hide or move under tests results. So that It does not take so much horizontal space. What can I try next?

I don't use the Go extension, but from a look at its settings, maybe try go.testExplorer.enable?

@super-starball-ultra Tried that, but this seem vs code feature.
